# Count not functioning to needs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code: `@String.Format("Total of {0} results", Model.Count())`

But it is only adding up the first page results I have paging on my index.cshtml and the count only takes in to account the first page how would this be fixed so it can take in all pages of the results on the Index.

Comment: Can you post your Action method?  Also, your model class definition.

Comment: All this is auto generated. I dont know how this will help as its the paging that is the problem if i remove paging its fine but i need paging that is why I ask for help.

Comment: @user1137472 even if it's auto generated, we need to see the logic on the server side how count is calculated (done by looking at the model definition). If you're paging client side, you need to ensure you're propagating the new count back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

If your controller returns only a part of the results to satisfy your paging mechanism, then you need to either use a ViewModel that will contain records collection and a property holding number of all records, or you need to setup additional action on your controller that will provide that number. Then you will retrieve it dynamically with jQuery for example.

It's hard to say what will solve your problem, as you didn't provide the code or details about  what kind of paging you're using, if you utilize webgrid or something else.